# how to change color Buttons once it is selected? and if input question

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, angularjs-ng-click

I have this code where I could only change the color once , i want the color of the selected button to change in each diffrent line.that in each line there will be only one button selected but for each line.
also i want to add one ,more button that is input button , but there is a way to create input button in angularjs-ng-click? i use angulerjs cause i want to do summery of the buttons in the end of the page.
here is a link to how it looks now   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI4pt.png

```
.prettyButton:focus {
  background-color:#3C8EB7;
}
.prettyButton {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 5px solid #3C8EB7;
  border-radius: 5px;

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script>angular.module('demo', []);</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="button_css.css">
    <script src="button_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="demo">
    <div class= "list_contain_q">
      <div class="queution_1">
        <div class="q1" style="color: black; font-size: 50px">   TOPIC  </div>
          <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="i = 1" ng-init="button1 = 'SPORT'">{{ button1 }}</button>
          <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="i = 3" ng-init="button3 = 'history'">{{ button3 }}</button>
          <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="i = 4" ng-init="button4 = 'music'">{{ button4 }}</button>
        <br></br>
        </div>
        <div class="queution_2">

        <div class="q2" style="color: black; font-size: 50px"> day   </div>
          <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="j = 12" ng-init="button12 = 'monday'">{{ button12 }}</button>
          <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="j = 22" ng-init="button22 = 'sunday'">{{ button22 }}</button>
          <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="j = 32" ng-init="button32 = 'friday'">{{ button32 }}</button>
          <br></br>
        </div>
        <div class="queution_3">
        <div class="q3" style="color: black; font-size: 50px">   houer   </div>
            <button  class ="prettyButton" ng-click="k = 123" ng-init="button123 = '16:00'">{{ button123 }}</button>
            <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="k = 223" ng-init="button223 = '17:00'">{{ button223 }}</button>
            <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="k = 323" ng-init="button323 = '18:00'">{{ button323 }}</button>
            <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="k = 423" ng-init="button423 = '19:00'">{{ button423 }}</button>
            <button class="prettyButton" ng-click="k = 523" ng-init="button523 = '20:00'">{{ button523 }}</button>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
        </div>
</div>
 <h2>summary</h2>
 <p class="sumamry" id = "sumamry_id" style="color: black; font-size: 40px; text-align: right;"> topic<input type="text" id = "topicbtn" value="this['button' + i]" ng-model="this['button' + i]" placeholder="topic"vstyle="color: black; font-size: 40px"> in day<input type="text" id="DayBtn" value="this['button' + j]" ng-model="this['button' + j]" placeholder="in day" style="color: black; font-size: 40px"> in hour <input type="text" id = "hourbtn" value="this['button' + k]" ng-model="this['button' + k]" placeholder="time"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of a selected button, use `element.style.color`. Here's an example:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('colorChangeButton'); // Gets the button
var clr = document.getElementById('clr'); // Gets the color
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => { // When the button is clicked...
btn.style.color = clr.value; // Set the button's color to the value of the color picker
});
```

```html
<button id="colorChangeButton">Change my color!</button>
<input type=color id="clr">
```

This is a simple example that allows you to change the color of a button to the value of a color picker. It gets the color value with `clr.value` and sets the new color with `btn.style.color = clr.value`.